# Make Autohotkey click on specific buttons in chrome

Tags: autohotkey

**I'm aware that you need the edge browser to make autohotkey click on specific things by finding out its ID.**

But the problem that I ran into, is that the site that I need for my script, **only allows you to open it with chrome**.

What solution do you guys recommend for this situation.
*I have tried finding the buttons ID, but I think you can actually only do that in the normal internet-explorer.*

Is there some sort of AddIn or something that I could install?

I would appreciate any input and help.

Comment: You could look into [Chrome.ahk](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=42890)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.Evaluate("document.getElementById('myBtn').click();")`

You should use AHK chrome library.